# Can I call ToolsAPI from code in the DUnit GUITestrunner?

Tags: delphi, dunit, opentools

Is there a way to initialize the global variable BorlandIDEServices in ToolSAPI unit so that it can be used from the DUnit GUITestrunner code?

```
procedure TGUITestRunner.FailureListViewClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Project: IOTAProject;
begin
  if FailureListView.Selected <> nil then
  begin
    TestTree.Selected := TTreeNode(FailureListView.Selected.data);

    // call OTA
    Project := ToolsAPI.GetActiveProject;
    ShowMessage(Project.ProjectType);

  end;
end;
```

In this example, the Project variable will be nil because the BorlandIDEServices variable is not initialized. The GUITestrunner is run from within the IDE in debug mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because `BorlandIDEServices` is only available from code actually running inside (as part of) the IDE itself. Code executing in external applications through the debugger are still running externally; they're not part of the IDE, even though the debugger is, and therefore don't have access to the `ToolsAPI` functionality.

Tools like [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org) actually plug into the IDE and become part of it, which is why they can access `ToolsAPI` interfaces. This isn't the case with `GUITestRunner`; it's an external application whether it's running under the debugger or not.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can imagine (have not tested it) would require a OTA plugin which communicates with the GUITestrunner over some inter process communication.

For example, the plugin opens a socket and receives commands like 'open file 'SomeTests.pas' in the editor' from the GUITestrunner application.

Comment: Or you could incorporate DUnit in the plugin directly, execute tests in a (dockable) form from within the IDE directly.

Comment: I've always wanted to be able to have a DUnit Exe pipe the test results to a DUnit plugin, being displayed in a toolwindow. Using a DUnit DLL (and loading into the Delphi address space) is fraught with danger and is liable to kill Delphi if your tests are bad.